# How to return to the shell/terminal?

Tags: command-line

Sometimes after I accidentally typing something in the terminal, e.g. after invoking a "tee" command I am unable to quit from that program to get back to the terminal. I usually try typing :q, quit, CTRL-Break, but nothing helps. So I close the terminal and open a new instance. Is there a standard way to quit from the executing command?

Comment: Another option is Ctrl+\. Like Ctrl+C, programs can catch the signal generated by Ctrl+\ and keep running if they want to, but very few programs do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> key to terminate a running process in command line

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference b/w CTRL+C and CTRL+Z in that case?

Comment: [Ctrl+C sends a signal to the the program to exit, while Ctrl+Z suspends the program](http://superuser.com/a/262948/180990). The program in question can choose what to do when receiving the signal from Ctrl+C, whereas Ctrl+Z stops it right away. You should only use Ctrl+Z when Ctrl+C doesn't work (since Ctrl+C gives the program the chance to clean up temporary files and so on).

Comment: @evilsoup: As noted in a comment under the answer you linked to, Ctrl+Z also sends a signal (SIGTSTP) that is catchable (although very few programs do so). And, to clarify *the above* answer, if you type Ctrl+C and get a shell prompt back, you have terminated the running process. If you type Ctrl+Z and get a shell prompt back, you have only *suspended* the process – it’s still alive, just not running.